# Определение угла коробки

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('images/04.jpg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 0)

edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=0, threshold2=70)

cv2.imshow("Result", edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Вот код, он определяет контуры вот этой фотографии:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как определить, под каким углом находится эта коробка? Именно под каким углом верхняя грань.

Comment: углом относительно текущей плоскости?

Comment: да, можно углом относительно плоскости, на которой он находится

Comment: тут нужно еще контуры плоскости определить. построить векторы и найти разницу их наклона вроде

Comment: может тогда как-то можно относительно камеры искать угол? Ну то есть на фото например 0 градусов, чуть повернуть будет там 15?